# how to handle multiple GET request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get

I am developing an online shop in Laravel, I want to filter products on categories, tags and price range.
when I click :

`<a href="{{ route('shop.show', ['category' => 'testCategory'])}}">Test Category </a>`

it should redirect me to : `shop?category=testCategory` and that's OK.

and when I click `<a href="{{ route('shop.show', ['tag' => 'testTag'])}}">Test Tag </a>`
it redirects me to : `shop?tag=testTag` 
And here is the problem, the one product has one category but could multiple tags or multiple tags and between specific price range
so, what I want is:

when the user is in: `shop?category=testCategory` and clicks on 
`<a href="{{ route('shop.show', ['tag' => 'testTag'])}}">Test Tag </a>`
he should be redirected to: `shop?category=testCategory&tag=testTag` **not to** `shop?tag=testTag` and drop category filter

I hope i was able to explain this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add several query parameters to your route like so:

```
<a href="{{ route('shop.show', ['category' => 'testCategegory', 'tag' => 'testTag'])}}">Test Tag </a>
```

Does this answer your question?